# how to exclude third party lib / dll from getting analyzed in CLANG scan-build xcodebuild?

Tags: clang, scan-build

I have used some open-source code and third party libs in my project and want to exclude that code from getting analyzed while analyzing my project using scan-build file.
I know we can #ifndef **clang_analyzer**  use this macro to suppress the code from getting analysed, but I dont want to copy paste this in all the files.

OR 
Is there any way so that the report which get generated after analysis using scan-build command, not to show the warnings/error generated from some set of files?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I use '-Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL' for gcc but it seems the linker flag to be lacking on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Use `--exclude` [[1]](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22594) [[2]](https://reviews.llvm.org/D52153) option (available since 2018)

> --exclude
>
> Do not run static analyzer against files found in this    directory
>   (You can specify this option multiple times).    Could be useful when
>   project contains 3rd party libraries.

Same is applicable for Python implementation of `scan-build` (`$ pip install scan-build`) - https://github.com/rizsotto/scan-build